# Create a table in Cassandra 1.2 with CQL3 where column names will be created at runtime

Tags: nosql, cassandra, cql

I want to store snapshots of an object in Apache Cassandra 1.2

Row key is the Object#ID and there will be a column for each snapshot.

```
--------    latest  --------   v2   -------- v1
id-122      100     --------   50   -------- 66
--------
```

So column names are created dynamically at runtime.

How to create the previous table in **Cassandra 1.2** using ***CQL3***?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use the compound primary key feature of CQL3:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
  object_id int,
  version int,
  value int,
  PRIMARY KEY (object_id, version));
```

Answer (score 0):

In CQL3, Table schema is fixed. So you can't really get dynamic column names. For that you have to switch to CQL2.

Comment: The schema is fixed, but things like compound keys and collections allow you to do everything you can in Thrift and CQL2, and more.

Comment: @Theo: Rightly said. But i belief, its not possible to use collection in a handy way, due to the lacking of secondary indexes, and yes please rectify me if i am wrong. That's why for me my choice is still CQL2.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE example (id1 TEXT, id2 TEXT, value TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (id1, id2))` <-- `id1` is row key, `id2` is column key, `value` is column value. Just like in the Thrift API and CQL2.

Comment: `CREATE INDEX my_index ON example (id2)` <-- secondary index in CQL3.

Comment: I am talking about secondary index on a collection(list,map & set) field, not the normal one.

Comment: To add columns in CQL3 we have to use `ALTER Table` clause